# Start Spark via Mesos

Tags: apache-spark, mesos

I am trying to start Spark via Mesos cluster, I have successfully run spark dispatcher via mesos master and register spark framework. But when i am trying to start any job (spark-submit or spark-shell) inicializing stop and happens nothing.

```
I0708 16:30:43.319941 21373 sched.cpp:157] Version: 0.22.1
I0708 16:30:43.331514 21375 sched.cpp:254] New master detected at master@host
I0708 16:30:43.333658 21375 sched.cpp:264] No credentials provided. Attempting to register without authentication
```

After that client freeze and that all

Comment: When you register spark as framework on mesos web ui do you have cero ram and cpu? Because I have the same problem and I note that spark framework register without resource allocated on mesos web ui.

Comment: Hi! I dont remember now, but I had enough resources on Mesos UI, sum of all my nodes (cpu and ram)

Comment: then you solve the problem?

Comment: No, I had to solve this issue fast and decided to use yarn

Comment: well, @IamMan you can use my solution on mesos

Comment: thank you @kikicarbonell, i will try it

Answer (score 2):

I solved same problem with [solution propose by @besil](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31164725/spark-mesos-dispatcher):

**Step1:** start the dispatcher using:

```
--master mesos://zk://<master_host>:2181/mesos
```

**Step2:** submit applications with:

```
spark-submit --deploy-mode cluster <other options> --master mesos://<dispatcher_ip>:7077 --class <class_name> <jar>
```

Hope this helps